# Understanding 3D visualization difference between ArcScene and ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: polygon, 3d, arcgis-pro, visualisation, arcscene

For research on (3D) noise mapping, I calculated the noise levels that reach the facades of buildings. The first picture shows the houses in 3D that I have used to determine the facades for the noise calculations.

[image: picture of the used houses for the calculations]

With the software program GeoMilieu (a spatial noise calculation program) I calculated on vertical grids with an distance interval of 1 meter on all facades. This resulted in the following output (a shapefile opened in ArcScene):

[image: Noise levels (from purple to green) on building facades]

The small gaps between buildings are caused by the fact that the interval is 1 meter, and only intermediate values could be interpolated, leaving the edges empty of calculated noise data.

However, when I open this exact same shapefile in ArcGIS Pro, I get a totally different visualization:

[image: Same shapefile opened in ArcGIS Pro]

I have no clue how this difference could happen.

- It is not something with the symbology (I tried everything there)
- Both shapefiles have the exact same amount of Polygon ZM objects in the attribute tables.
- The 'white' missing parts in the ArcGIS Pro visualization cannot be selected or identified, in ArcScene clicking on the exact same part of a building (even though 'visualized') does not result in a selection or identification.
- The white parts are always the same parts and are not 'flickering' or changing when panning around in the 3D modus (no rendering issues)

Comment: What are the precise and detailed steps that you performed to get your ArcGIS Pro result?  Have you tried the same steps in the latest version of ArcGIS Pro (2.4.2, and soon to be 2.5)?  Are you viewing in a Local Scene or a Global Scene view?  Can you reproduce this using a simple test dataset like an extruded square building footprint?